# How to concat thousands of pandas dataframes generated by a for loop efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

Thousands of dfs of consistent columns are being generated in a for loop reading different files, and I'm trying to merge / concat / append them into a single df, `combined`:

```
combined = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(1,1000): # demo only
    global combined
    generate_df() # df is created here
    combined = pd.concat([combined, df])
```

This is initially fast but slows as `combined` grows, eventually becoming unusably slow. [This answer on how to append rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57001947/4107349) explains how adding rows to a dict and then creating a df is most efficient but I can't figure out how to do that with `to_dict`.

What's a good way to to this? Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create list of DataFrames and then use `concat` only once:

```
dfs = []

for i in range(1,1000): # demo only
    global combined
    generate_df() # df is created here
    dfs.append(df)

combined = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: Ah, fantastic. I incorrectly thought appending dfs of the same name to a list wouldn't work but this is perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

The fastest way is building a list of dictionaries and building the dataframe only once at the end:

```py
rows = []

for i in range(1, 1000):
    # Instead of generating a dataframe, generate a dictionary
    dictionary = generate_dictionary()
    rows.append(dictionary)

combined = pd.DataFrame(rows)
```

This is about 100 times faster that concatenating dataframes, as is proved by the [benchmark here](https://perfpy.com/3).

Comment: Hmm but what if every df contains tens of thousands of rows? Will creating a dataframe from list of that many dicts still outperform cocating a handful of dfs?

Comment: This simple benchmark using 10 dataframes with 10k rows each shows that it's still way faster using dictionaries: https://perfpy.com/563

The reason is that pandas need to transform the data into it's own data structure and that is expensive. And it depends on the number of rows as well. Better do it once instead of many times.

Answer (score 2):

- Use `concat` only once at the end.
- Sort the index of each DataFrame. In my production code this sort didn't take long yet reduced the processing time of `concat` from 10 + seconds to less than one second!

---

```
dfs = []

for i in range(1,1000): # demo only
    global combined
    df = generate_df() # df is created here
    df.sort_index(inplace=True)    
    dfs.append(df)

combined = pd.concat(dfs)
```