# How can I speed up hash comparison that seems to limited by lots of database calls?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hash, amazon-rds

I am dealing with a Django web app that needs to perform a hash comparison on +10M string hashes that are 64 characters long. I take the 100 most similar hashes and return them to the user; similarity is based on a hamming distance (number of characters that are the same). All of this happens in the backend of the Django server, which I suspect is not the best place to put this code. The basic workflow is this user makes a POST request -> passes through my views.py, which hashes the POST data -> hash is passed to below code.

```
from hexhamming import hamming_distance_string
from django.conf import settings
import psycopg2 as pg
import panadas as pd

def _hamming_distance(hash1, hash2):
    return hamming_distance_string(hash1, hash2)

def compare_image_hashes(hash):

    result_df = pd.DataFrame({'key': [], 'hash': [], 'difference':[]})  # Empty dataframe for all results

    MAX_CURSOR_PULL = settings.MAX_CURSOR_PULL   # Max amount of results for the PG cursor
    SIMILARITY = settings.SIMILARITY # Value to determine if an image is similar
    LIMIT = settings.LIMIT


    conn = pg.connect(
            database=settings.DATABASE['DATABASE_NAME'],
            user=settings.DATABASE['DATABASE_USER'],
            password=settings.DATABASE['DATABASE_PASSWORD'],
            host=settings.DATABASE['DATABASE_HOST'],
            port=settings.DATABASE['DATABASE_PORT']
        )

    cursor = conn.cursor('hash-cursor')
    cursor.itersize = MAX_CURSOR_PULL # Redudant limit

    query = "SELECT hash, key FROM hashes LIMIT %s;" % LIMIT
    cursor.execute(query)

    chunk = cursor.fetchmany(MAX_CURSOR_PULL)
    columns = [desc[0] for desc in cursor.description]

    while chunk:    # Continue while there are still results
        df = pd.DataFrame(chunk, columns=columns)

        df['difference'] = [_hamming_distance(hash, x.strip()) for x in df['hash']]    # Add a column for the hash difference of the image

        if result_df.empty: # If there are no results
            result_df = df.query('difference <= %s' % SIMILARITY)
        else:   # If there are results concat the two dataframes
            result_df = pd.concat([result_df, df.query('difference <= %s' % SIMILARITY)])

        chunk = cursor.fetchmany(MAX_CURSOR_PULL)


    result_df = result_df.sort_values('difference', kind="mergesort")[:100]

    return result_df
```

My issues are related to speed. When I do get a successful response it is after a long ~90 second wait, or a timeout error occurs. I am dealing with an AWS EC2 instance with that hosts this web app, as well as two others. The instance has 30vCPU, 256 GB of memory, and 3TB of disk space. The hashes are stored in a Postgres AWS RDS instance accessible to the server. Python 3.10.13, Pandas 2.1.X, Psycopg2 2.X, and Django 3.12.4

I believe my issue lies in the fact that I have make so many database calls in order to get through all +10M hashes. I cannot grab all the items at once or in big chunks as the EC2 instance cannot handle it.

## Solutions I've tried/thought of:

I've tried speeding up the hashing process as much as possible using the [hexhamming](https://pypi.org/project/hexhamming/) library, which did see a substantial increase for the hamming distance calculations, but I am still seeing slow speeds/occasional timeouts.

I've also tried parallelizing the fetching/hamming distance calculations on a local machine, but saw no improvement.

As a junior I am struggling with ways to optimize this as it seems it may require better architecting. Ideas that come to my head are **1)** taking the hash-fetching/hamming off of the EC2 instance and onto it's own server or maybe LAMBDA where it might be able to either fetch from the database in larger batches without jeopardizing the other web apps or store a temp static version of the database in memory so that it doesn't have to make so many PG calls (we originally had the db set up on the EC2 and that also had speed problems) **2)** Using some sort of parallelization off of the server to handle the task of grabbing a chunk of hashes and hamming them.

This is my first question and I hope I provided all the necessary info, sorry it is so long and complex!

Comment: You'd want to do the [Hamming distance calculation in the PostgreSQL server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/72134/255118) instead of grabbing everything over the wire and comparing it. Also, there's absolutely no need to use Pandas here...

Comment: Worth mentioning that using pd.concat() inside a loop causes concat's execution time to grow quadratically. There's a more efficient alternative here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65773511/how-to-concat-thousands-of-pandas-dataframes-generated-by-a-for-loop-efficiently

Comment: Hexhamming has a function called [`check_hexstrings_within_dist`](https://github.com/mrecachinas/hexhamming#example), which might be faster, as it stops calculating dist when it detects that it is above the threshold.