# From a pandas DataFrame, read each line of the json url and return the data

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have the code below, bringing data from a table converting into DataFrame. From that, I include a column with the API url + the zip code of each line. When reading each Json URL, I need to return the latitude and longitude, but I'm only getting this data from the last line, not each of them.

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
import urllib.request
import requests

con_db = psycopg2.connect(host='', database='', user='', password='')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE district = 'Monjolos' limit 10")
result = cursor.fetchall()
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.columns = [columns[0] for columns in cursor.description]

url_api = 'https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/'
df['url_api'] = url_api + df['zip_code']

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = url_api + row['url_api']
    open_json = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(open_json.read())
    df['coord'] = data['lat'] + ', ' + data['lng']
    
print(df[['id', 'url_api', 'coord']])
```

Result:

```
     id                                      url_api                     coord
0  3748  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24722120  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
1  3859  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24722610  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
2  3860  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24722630  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
3  3863  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24722670  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
4  3882  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24723000  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
5  3883  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24723002  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
6  3884  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24723003  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
7  3885  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24723004  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
8  3886  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24723005  -22.8147264, -42.9442479
9  3887  https://cep.awesomeapi.com.br/json/24723006  -22.8147264, -42.9442479

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line in the `for loop` assign the value to the entire column on each iteration. Use `loc` to assign to value to the current index.

```
df.loc[index, 'coord'] = data['lat'] + ', ' + data['lng']
```

Comment: A single detail I missed. I even used df.loc, but forgot to insert the 'index'. Worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
coord = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    url = url_api + row['url_api']
    open_json = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    data = json.loads(open_json.read())
    coord.append(data['lat'] + ', ' + data['lng'])
df['coord'] = coord
```

Comment: Thanks for the support. It also worked with the last two lines.

Comment: @LinoCosta I hope using list will be faster [`What is the fastest and most efficient way to append rows to a DataFrame?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57000903/what-is-the-fastest-and-most-efficient-way-to-append-rows-to-a-dataframe)